# How to check if a pandas dataframe contains only numeric values column-wise?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, series

I want to check every column in a dataframe whether it contains only numeric data. Specifically, my query is not about the datatype, but instead, I want to check every value in each column of the dataframe whether it's a numeric value.

How can I find this out?

Comment: Actually I need to reframe my question I think. My query is not in the datatype level instead i need to check every value in each column of dataframe whether its contains numeric values only

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You can check that using `to_numeric` and coercing errors:

```
pd.to_numeric(df['column'], errors='coerce').notnull().all()
```

For all columns, you can iterate through columns or just use `apply`

```
df.apply(lambda s: pd.to_numeric(s, errors='coerce').notnull().all())
```

---

E.g.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col' : [1,2, 10, np.nan, 'a'], 
                   'col2': ['a', 10, 30, 40 ,50],
                   'col3': [1,2,3,4,5.0]})
```

Outputs

```
col     False
col2    False
col3     True
dtype: bool
```

Comment: Though I guess there's a question as to whether `NaN` counts as numeric: `np.issubdtype(type(np.NaN), np.number)`

Comment: Yes ALollz, for my application at the moment, np.Nan is a perfectly fine numeric value, so i want to get "True" for 1.23423, "True" for np.NaN, but "False" for, say, [1.,2.] or "hello"

Comment: This is not working with Pandas 2.2 when using the new ```dtype_backend="pyarrow"``` backend. Maybe to do with np.NaN not being correctly recognized as a null.

Answer (score 10):

You can draw a True / False comparison using `isnumeric()`

### Example:

```
 >>> df
       A      B
0      1      1
1    NaN      6
2    NaN    NaN
3      2      2
4    NaN    NaN
5      4      4
6   some   some
7  value  other
```

### Results:

```
>>> df.A.str.isnumeric()
0     True
1      NaN
2      NaN
3     True
4      NaN
5     True
6    False
7    False
Name: A, dtype: object

# df.B.str.isnumeric()
```

with `apply()` method which seems more robust in case you need corner to corner comparison:

DataFrame having two different columns one with mixed type another with numbers only for test:

```
>>> df
       A   B
0      1   1
1    NaN   6
2    NaN  33
3      2   2
4    NaN  22
5      4   4
6   some  66
7  value  11
```

Result:

```
>>> df.apply(lambda x: x.str.isnumeric())
       A     B
0   True  True
1    NaN  True
2    NaN  True
3   True  True
4    NaN  True
5   True  True
6  False  True
7  False  True
```

### Another example:

Let's consider the below dataframe with different data-types as follows..

```
>>> df
   num  rating    name  age
0    0    80.0  shakir   33
1    1   -22.0   rafiq   37
2    2   -10.0     dev   36
3  num     1.0   suraj   30
```

Based on the comment from OP on this answer, where it has negative value and 0's in it.

1- This is a pseudo-internal method to return only the numeric type data.

```
>>> df._get_numeric_data()
   rating  age
0    80.0   33
1   -22.0   37
2   -10.0   36
3     1.0   30
```

OR

2- there is an option to use method `select_dtypes` in module pandas.core.frame which return a subset of the DataFrame's columns based on the column `dtypes`. One can use `Parameters` with `include, exclude` options.

```
>>> df.select_dtypes(include=['int64','float64']) # choosing int & float
   rating  age
0    80.0   33
1   -22.0   37
2   -10.0   36
3     1.0   30

>>> df.select_dtypes(include=['int64'])  # choose int
   age
0   33
1   37
2   36
3   30
```

Comment: @ALollz, Just edited the answer forgot to put second datafarme example :-)

Comment: Works fine. Actually this command works for object data type only. Right ?

Comment: For example if my columns is of int type and it has negative value and 0's in it. How can i check their existence ?

Comment: @RajaSaheS, Just added more examples..  i see its old thread :-)

Answer (score 9):

This will return True if all columns are numeric, False otherwise.

```
df.shape[1] == df.select_dtypes(include=np.number).shape[1]
```

To select numeric columns:

```
new_df = df.select_dtypes(include=np.number)
```

Answer (score 4):

Let's say you have a dataframe called `df`, if you do:

```
df.select_dtypes(include=["float", 'int'])
```

This will return all the numeric columns, you can check if this is the same as the original `df`.

Otherwise, you can also use the `exclude` parameter:

```
df.select_dtypes(exclude=["float", 'int'])
```

and check if this gives you an empty dataframe.

Answer (score 3):

The accepted answers seem bit overkill, as they sub-select the entire dataframe.

To check types only metadata should be used, which can be done with
[pd.api.types.is_numeric_dtype](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.api.types.is_numeric_dtype.html).

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(data=[[1,'a']],columns=['numeruc_col','string_col'])

print(df.columns[list(map(pd.api.types.is_numeric_dtype,df.dtypes))]) # one way
print(df.dtypes.map(pd.api.types.is_numeric_dtype)) # another way
```

Comment: You're just checking the dtype. The accepted answer actually check whether the column is numeric, not just the dtype.

Comment: Using dtype gives more fine-grained control. Furthermore, this approach uses only metadata as it should be, instead of sub-slicing dataframe.

Comment: Then you are answering a different question. Read the question (and the clarifying comment on the question).

Comment: This is best answer. It returns False for col that has any nonnumbers. That is just what OP wanted

Answer (score 1):

To check for numeric columns, you could use `df[c].dtype.kind in 'iufcb'` where `c` is any given column name. The comparison will yeild a `True` or `False` boolean output.

It can be iterated through all the column names with a list comprehension:

```
>>> [(c, df[c].dtype.kind in 'iufcb') for c in df.columns]

[('col', False), ('col2', False), ('col3', True)]
```

The [numpy.dtype.kind](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.dtype.kind.html#numpy-dtype-kind) `'iufcb'` notation is a representation of whether it is a signed integer (i), unsigned integer (u), float (f), complex number (c), or boolean (b).  The string can be modified to exclude any of the above (e.g., `'iufc'` to exclude boolean).

This solves the original question in relation to checking column data types.  It also provides the benefits of (1) a shorter line of code which (2) remains sufficiently intuitive to the user.