# check if pandas data frame column (string/object) is numeric (ignore empty/NULL/NAN)

Tags: python, pandas

I tried this inspired by the accepted answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54426845/how-to-check-if-a-pandas-dataframe-contains-only-numeric-column-wise):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1':['1', '']})
all_numeric = pd.to_numeric(df['col1'], errors='coerce').notnull().all().item()
print(all_numeric)
```

to detect that a columns is numeric (ignoring blanks + NULLs + NANs).

In the above code all_numeric is False (Python bool), which does not make sense or maybe it does? I thought I try to impute nan as the reason might be the empty value:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1':['1', '']})
df = df.apply(lambda x: x.str.strip()).replace('', np.nan)
all_numeric = pd.to_numeric(df['col1'], errors='coerce').notnull().all().item()
print(all_numeric)
```

Same outcome. Maybe my way of checking if all values of a column are numeric (ignoring NULL/NAN/empty strings) is wrong? Thanks!

Comment: please add your data

Comment: @anon01 ??? is df = pd.DataFrame({'col1':['1', '']}) not data?

Comment: I missed that, aplolgies

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could strip white spaces and convert empty string to NaN, then drop it; then do the test:

```
out = pd.to_numeric(df['col1'].str.strip().replace('', pd.NA).dropna(), errors='coerce').notna().all().item()
```

Output:

```
True
```

This test throws False for the following input:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1':['1', 's']})
```

Comment: I am sorry I do not follow. Are you saying I should remove notnull()?

Comment: thanks. so how do I check if all values of a column are numeric (type object/string) ignoring empty entries, NULLs and NANs?

Comment: thanks but I want the logic for numeric detection ignore this and nulls and nans

Comment: no I do not - sorry

Comment: this is actually why I have df = df.apply(lambda x: x.str.strip()).replace('', np.nan)

Comment: yes that is what I want - I rewrote my question as well ...

Comment: please add .item() to get python bool

Comment: Bizarrely it does not work for negative values?! df = pd.DataFrame({'col1':['-1', ' ']})

Comment: @cs0815 that doesn't work because not because of negative value but because the string is not empty string `''`, it's white space `' '`.

Comment: it does not work for df = pd.DataFrame({'col1':['-1', '1']})

Comment: @cs0815 that's weird, it works for me. What version of pandas do you have?

Answer (score -1):

According to the [official pandas doc](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.isnumeric.html), you can check a series of data if it's numeric or not.

```
>>df = pd.DataFrame({'col1':['1', '']})
>>df.col1.str.isnumeric()

0     True
1    False
```

Comment: df['col1'].str.isnumeric().mean() might work ...

Comment: Do you want to retrieve those cols which contain numeric values?

Comment: no I just want to transform them to numeric if there cardinality is also above threshold. long story

Comment: Can you add some sample output?

Comment: My example is pretty self explanatory I think?