# Sum percentages by condition

Tags: python, sum, conditional-statements

everyone.
I don't know how to solve this.
I would like to sum the percentages according to the result.
Let me explain; all the % values for example with result i -1 should be summed (leaving the sign unchanged, so -1578 + -0.987, etc., then when the sign changes, the value goes to zero and it starts summing those results with value 1.
Eventually in the column I would have something like this:

| Date | Sign | % | res | sum |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2020-10-06 | 1.0 | -1.594774 | -1 | -1.594774 |
| 2020-10-07 | 1.0 | 1.847843 | 1 |  |
| 2020-10-08 | 1.0 | 0.493660 | 1 |  |
| 2020-10-09 | 1.0 | 1.372718 | 1 |  |
| 2020-10-12 | 1.0 | 2.495056 | 1 | 6.209277 |
| 2020-10-13 | 1.0 | -0.104176 | -1 |  |
| 2020-10-14 | 1.0 | -0.808668 | -1 |  |
| 2020-10-15 | 1.0 | -0.468337 | -1 |  |
| 2020-10-16 | 1.0 | -0.362510 | -1 |  |
| 2020-10-19 | -1.0 | -1.678558 | -1 | -3,422249 |
| 2020-10-20 | -1.0 | 0.326578 | 1 |  |
| 2020-10-21 | -1.0 | -0.276889 | -1 |  |
| 2020-10-22 | -1.0 | 0.185289 | 1 |  |
| 2020-10-23 | -1.0 | 0.366033 | 1 |  |
| 2020-10-26 | -1.0 | -1.666879 | -1 |  |

I tried this code but the result is wrong. I can't understand why it sums incorrectly.

```
summ = 0
fin = []
for sm in df1['res']:
    if sm == 1:
        summ += df1['%'] 
        fin.append(summ)
    elif sm == -1:
        summ += df1['%'] 
        fin.append(summ)

fin
```

---

```
[Date
 2020-10-06    -754.327977
 2020-10-07     874.029912
 2020-10-08     233.501375
 2020-10-09     649.295754
 2020-10-12    1180.161504
                  ...     
 2022-08-16     -92.054601
 2022-08-17    -601.132479
 2022-08-18      99.302686
 2022-08-19    -968.395810
 2022-08-22   -1236.403534
 Name: %, Length: 473, dtype: float64,
 Date
 2020-10-06    -754.327977
 2020-10-07     874.029912
 2020-10-08     233.501375
 2020-10-09     649.295754
 2020-10-12    1180.161504
```

I would also like to add fin in the df1.
I tried `df1['fin'] = fin`, but it gives me no result.
Any ideas, thanks

Comment: I cannot understand the process. I think both `sm == 1` and `sm == -1` do the same logic in the for loop.

Comment: Actually when it changes sign (-1 and then meets 1) the sum has to reset and start again from zero. So as long as I have negative sign (-1) all the values in the '%' column add up and I get a negative cumulative sum, when it changes sign (1) it starts from zero taking the positive values in the row and sums them, until the sign changes.

Comment: as you can see from the table, the first value of 'res' is -1, so the value in the cell corresponding to '%' is taken and put in the 'sum' column. Then the next sign is positive (1) and so for the next 3 rows. Then sum all 4 rows and I get the cumulative sum. Change sign, reset everything and start the sum again.

Answer (score 2):

Assume that you want to keep a subtotal of all consecutive rows that have the same res value, you need to keep track of the current res value and change your code accordingly:

```
summ = 0
fin = []

current_sm = df1['res'][0] # this is so the code work with first index
for index, sm in enumerate(df1['res']):
    if sm == current_sm: # same res value as previous, keep adding to the sum
        summ += df1['%'][index]
    else: # res change, save the subtotal, setup for the next
       fin.append(summ)
       current_sm = sm
       summ = df1['%'][index]
fin.append(summ) # Collect subtotal for the last batch
```

Comment: Hi Harvey Pham, meanwhile, thank you for responding, but I think there is some error, because the summed values are strange. 2020-10-06   -8.192116e+207
 2020-10-07    9.492097e+207
 2020-10-08    2.535860e+207
 2020-10-09    7.051450e+207
 2020-10-12    1.281673e+208. 
as you can see it doesn't sum the values sequentially but apparently they seem meaningless.

Comment: I forgot that df1['%'] represent the whole column. Can you checkout my latest update?

Comment: Tried. But from this result:  [-inf,
 inf,
 -inf,
 inf,
 -inf,
 inf,
 -inf,
 inf, ,,,,]

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame({'%':[-1.594774,1.847843,0.493660,1.372718,2.495056,-0.104176,-0.808668,-0.468337,-0.362510,-1.678558,0.326578,-0.276889,0.185289,0.366033,-1.666879],
                   'res':[-1,1,1,1,1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,1,-1,1,1,-1]})
```

Initialize sum column:

```
df['sum'] = np.nan
```

First figure out the index where the sign change is happening:

```
l = df.index[df['res']!=df['res'].shift(-1)]
```

The indices:

```
Int64Index([0, 4, 9, 10, 11, 13, 14], dtype='int64')
```

Then loop through this list and calculate the sum of sub-sequence:

```
df.loc[l[0],'sum'] = df.loc[0:l[0],'%'].sum()

for i in range(1,len(l)):
    df.loc[l[i],'sum'] = df.loc[l[i-1]+1:l[i],'%'].sum()
```

Output:

```
           %  res       sum
0  -1.594774   -1 -1.594774
1   1.847843    1       NaN
2   0.493660    1       NaN
3   1.372718    1       NaN
4   2.495056    1  6.209277
5  -0.104176   -1       NaN
6  -0.808668   -1       NaN
7  -0.468337   -1       NaN
8  -0.362510   -1       NaN
9  -1.678558   -1 -3.422249
10  0.326578    1  0.326578
11 -0.276889   -1 -0.276889
12  0.185289    1       NaN
13  0.366033    1  0.551322
14 -1.666879   -1 -1.666879
```

Comment: Hi Sri Harsha, thanks for the code. Unfortunately it gives me an error:   -- TypeError: Addition/subtraction of integers and integer-arrays with Timestamp is no longer supported.  Instead of adding/subtracting `n`, use `n * obj.freq` --- in this part of code: df1.loc[l[i],'sum'] = df1.loc[l[i-1]+1:l[i],'%'].sum()

Comment: Probably you might have dates in your % column. Please check if all the values in that column are numeric. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54426845/how-to-check-if-a-pandas-dataframe-contains-only-numeric-column-wise

Comment: Checked. There is no error. % are all numbers. Ttry with: df1.apply(lambda x: x.isnull()).sum(). Output: Sign         0, %            0, res    0, dtype: int64

Comment: To be on the safe side, I also used this: df1.select_dtypes(include=['float64']). No error.

Comment: x.null() only checks for missing values. Try casting the column to number properly at the start with pd.to_numeric()

Comment: I reviewed the code. It gives me a different error. I wrote it down for you under the question I asked at the beginning. If you can take a look at it, thank you

Answer (score 0):

I am writing here for Sri Harsha, with those small spaces I cannot post the code and the various errors.

```
df1['sum'] = np.nan
l = df1.index[df1['res']!= df1['res'].shift(-1)]
df1.loc[l[0],'sum'] = df1.loc[0:l[0],'%'].sum()

for i in range(1,len(l)):
    df1.loc[l[i],'sum'] = df1.loc[l[i-1]+1:l[i],'%'].sum()

df1['sum']
```

Point of error:

```
1 df1['sum'] = np.nan
      2 l = df1.index[df1['res']!= df1['res'].shift(-1)]
----> 3 df1.loc[l[0],'sum'] = df1.loc[0:l[0],'%'].sum()
      5 for i in range(1,len(l)):
      6     df1.loc[l[i],'sum'] = df1.loc[l[i-1]+1:l[i],'%'].sum()
```

TypeError: cannot do slice indexing on DatetimeIndex with these indexers [0] of type int

Comment: Could it be that your dataframe is multiindexed?. Try reset index

Comment: Oh, yes, perfect! I thank you very much. I didn't quite understand what it does with .loc. I have to study this well because I'm still too poor. Anyway thank you